# return a list of numbers in scala for which a predicate holds

Tags: scala

I want to write a function in scala `calcMod(a, b, c)` where `a` should serve as a predicate and `b` and `c` taking the range of numbers (e.g. 3(incl.)...9(excl.)) which have to be evaluated and return a list of numbers in this range for which the predicate holds.

For example the function-call `calcMod(k => k % 2 == 0, 3, 9)` should evaluate in `Return(4, 6, 8)`

The fact that I have `mod 2 == 0` makes it clear that even numbers will always be returned. I want to solve this with linear recursion.

```
def calcMod(a: Int => Boolean, b: Int, c: Int): List[Int] = ?
```

Comment: What's wrong with `3 until 9 filter(_ % 2 == 0)`? Why reinvent anything at all here?

Comment: Hi @FrankS, welcome to StackOverflow. You may take a look to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially, you should provide some research effort and/or some code to probe you already tried to solve your problem by yourself. BTW, I'm sure you're doing this for an assignment or for learning since as Andrey already point out you can just use the built-in methods `to` and `filter` instead of doing plain recursion - so maybe try something and if you get stuck come here, we will be happy to help. As an advice think on the base case first.

Answer (score 0):

Below function will go from b until c, then apply filter with the function we got in argument.

```
 def calcMod(a: Int => Boolean, b: Int, c: Int): List[Int] = (b until c filter a).toList
```

Comment: Do you want to add some explanations what your code does?